# Android enable Real-time developer notifications for your app via API

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I can setup pub/sub topic via API, but I can't find api method for set Real-time developer notifications in Google Play Console(Monetize > Monetization setup).

It's possible to do **via API**? Or only via web interface?

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready#enable-rtdn

[image]

Comment: is the notification different from firebase cloud messaging?

Comment: yes, I think it's different methods